Is there a report that shows what is duplicated between contacts ? For example: contacts sharing an email, or a phone number
Is there a report that shows what  is duplicated between contacts ? For example: contacts sharing an email, or a phone number. In other words, they have duplicate data, but they are actually not duplicate contacts.
Contacts can share an email in civicrm, but if they do, only one of them can have a drupal user account and I would like to alert them.

You can use searchkit to identify and report exactly who has duplicate fields and what the value is like the following:
Search by contact entity for the field, in this case email, and sort by count >1. The result is a list of contact pairs using the same email with the email value listed.
(Count) Contact ID  (List) Sort Name    (List) Contact Type (List) Contact Subtype  Primary Email
2   Last1, first1, last2, First2    Individual  Resident    sharedemail1@gmail.com
2   Last3, First3, last4, First4    Individual  Resident    sharedemail2@msn.com
2   Last5, First5, Last6, First6    Individual  Resident    sharedemail3@gmail.com

